# How should we think while translating '' thus or thereby + ing ''?

Tags: meaning, grammar

1-) The initial event is removal of an electron from the hydrogen atom, **thus converting it to a hydrogen ion.**

2-) She forgot to tie her shoes, **thereby or thus tripping and falling down the stairs.**

3-) He knocked over the red wine, **thereby ruining the table cloth.**

4-) Regular exercise strengthens the heart, **thereby reducing the risk of heart attack.**

Hello. I found a few examples to explain the issue. I come across such phrases very often. I understand, but I couldn't grasp the logic. also i couldn't find any book that explains this topic in detail I usually think of these sentences as :

2-) **She forgot to tie her shoes** *thereby **she** tripped and falled down the stairs.*

1-) The initial event is removal of an electron from the hydrogen atom, thus **initial event** converts it to a hydrogen ion.

Is it true ?
However, How can I interpret this sentence :

4-) Regular exercise strengthens the heart, thereby reducing the risk of heart attack.???

Regular exercise strengthens the heart, thereby **it** reduces the risk of heart attack.

**it = *regular exercise* or *regular exercise strengthens the heart*** so whole sentence ?

Comment: I don't think (1) is a good example of the use of *thus*. The words *thus* and *thereby* ideally should modify verbs and not nouns, so (1) would be more grammatical if it read "Initially, an electron is removed from the hydrogen atom, thus converting it to a hydrogen ion."

Comment: I wouldn't use either _thus_ or _thereby_ in sentence 2. Leaving her shoelaces undone wasn't a means of falling downstairs - the fall was an unintended result.  I would say _as a result of which she tripped and fell downstairs._

Comment: @PeterShor *thus converting...* is a gerund phrase or a participle phrase: both are modified by adverbs.

Comment: @Greybeard: Yes, but I think the point is what does the _thus converting..._ clause modify? Usually it would modify a description of an action ("X did Y, thus converting...") but that's not present here, which is what makes that example awkward at best.

Comment: Are you translating *from* English or *to* English? If *from* English, why not give some real-world examples? If *to* English, why do you think you need to use "thus" and "thereby" at all?

Comment: @psmears *The initial event is removal of an electron from the hydrogen atom, thus converting it to a hydrogen ion.* = The initial event is removal of an electron from the hydrogen atom, **in that manner/by that action** converting it to a hydrogen ion.

Comment: @Greybeard: That's still ungrammatical (or at least incredibly awkward) to me. What is the subject of "converting"?

Comment: @psmears ? It hasn't got a subject - it's a non-finite clause. You can add an "and" if you want, but  *in that manner/by that action converting it to a hydrogen ion.* is basically describing what the removal of an electron does: https://www.google.com/search?q="thus%20converting%20it"&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1968,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_en

Comment: @greybeard:  Non-finite clauses can have (possibly implicit) subjects. To put it another way: who or what is doing the converting? I'm not sure what your search is intended to show. Every single example there (on the first page, at least, didn't check any further) has a preceding verb clause that "thus..." is qualifying, unlike the example in the question here. That would seem to suggest that it is indeed needed?

Comment: @psmears I'm afraid you've lost me. The loss of an electron (from a hydrogen atom) converts it (= a hydrogen atom)) to a hydrogen ion.:- It (= a hydrogen atom) loses an electron  thus converting it to a hydrogen ion.

Comment: @Greybeard: I understand the chemistry, it's the English I'm talking about. Your second example would be fine as "It loses an electron thus converting it**self** to a hydrogen ion" (or alternatively delete the "it" altogether and have "converting" be intransitive). But that is _not the same_ as the example in the question, which doesn't have the "It loses an electron" clause; instead it has "the initial event is XXX" (describing a state not an action); the "thus" doesn't have an action to qualify.

Comment: @Graybeard: "The most traumatic event of my childhood was the collapse of my neighbors' house, thus leaving them homeless." The word *thus* doesn't belong in that sentence, and it doesn't belong in the OP's original sentence for the same reason. Removing it greatly improves both sentences.

Answer (score 0):

[Thus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/thus) (Wiktionary) (manner) In this way or manner.

> If you throw the ball **thus**, as I’m showing you, you’ll have better
> luck hitting the target.

(conjunctive) As a result.

> I have all the tools I need; **thus**, I will be able to fix the car
> without having to call a mechanic.

[Therefore](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/therefore) (Wiktionary) (conjunctive) Consequently, by or in consequence of that or this cause; referring to something previously stated.

> Traditional values will always have a place. **Therefore**, they will
> never lose relevance.

(conjunctive, archaic) for that; for it (in reference to a previous statement)

> Behold, we have forsaken all, and followed thee; what shall we have
> **therefore**?

[Thereby](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/thereby) (Wiktionary) (formal) By it; by that; by that means, or as a consequence of that.

> This Constitution, and the Laws of the United States which shall be
> made in Pursuance thereof; and all Treaties made, or which shall be
> made, under the Authority of the United States, shall be the supreme
> Law of the Land; and the Judges in every State shall be bound **thereby**,
> any Thing in the Constitution or Laws of any State to the Contrary
> notwithstanding.

In some sentences all three can be used interchangeably. In some sentences not.

If we are to use some other phrases in places of **thus, therefore, thereby**, these are the phrases we are likely to use.

> **Thus**: In this way; for that reason.
> **Therefore**: For that reason.
> **Thereby**: As a result; by it; by that.

Do the exercise and kindly let us know in the form of an answer, which of these three **thus, therefore, thereby** you found most suitable for each sentence?